# Expected number of offers until house is sold

Tags: probability

> I am selling my house, and have decided to accept the first offering
> exceeding $K$ dollars. Assuming that offers are independent rv with
> common distribution $F$, find the expected number of offers received
> before I sell the house.

### Try

I call $X$ to be number of offers receiver before house is sold. Suppose we have $n$ such offers and call them $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$. Therefore, $X = \sum X_i$. We have that

$$ E(X) = E(X_1) + .. + E(X_n) $$

Since all $X_i$ have common distribution $F$, then

$$ E(X_i) = \int\limits_0^K x f(x) $$

where $f = F' $. So,

$$ E(X) = n \int\limits_0^K x f(x) $$

is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely the wrong way to do it. $F(K)$ gives the probability that one offer is less than $K$, i.e. the offer fails, so $1-F(K)$ is the probability of an offer succeeding. Now the number of offers received follows a geometric distribution with success rate $1-F(K)$, so the expected number of offers is its reciprocal, $\frac1{1-F(K)}$.